# IT Question: Two NICs with identical gateway metric

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista

Windows Vista Business with SP1

I have two NICs in my Vista Business SP1 machine - one NIC is connected to our corporate network, the other NIC is connected to a private network. Both networks are using DHCP, with the private network obtaining it's address from a LinkSys WRT54G (not being used as a router - just a switch with DHCP).

The problem I having is that both networks end up with a entry in the routing table for 0.0.0.0 with the same metric. So anytime I try to access the internet (which should always go through the corporate network), I have a 50-50 chance of actually succeeding.

How can I keep this from happening?

Thanks....

Comment: I don't believe this is programming related.

Answer (score 1):

I think your simplest solution will be to just assign a static IP to your NIC on your private network.  When you assign a static IP just do not specify a gateway address.

I could be wrong but I don't think the WRT54G can be modified to not provide a Gateway over DHCP.